# Defining labels for Accessibility spoken feedback

Tags: java, android, accessibility, text-to-speech

I'm looking for how to do texttospeech from extern file, eg from resources.

Normally it works that, it read view's text/className/etc .

There would be great to click on specific view eg unnamed button with only image, and tts from resource with mapped strings.

**EDIT:**
Yes it goes for TalkBack, yes It reads "Button", and I would like to assign it a specific string. 
Also assign text for specific button even if it has text assigned in xml layout.

EG:

```
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/this_is_button"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

and it will read the content from android:text. Or just "Button" if we have not assigned text here.

The problem is how to assign for this button another text which would be read.

Comment: Are you talking about Accessibility service that reads text from the screen (like TalkBack) and the case that it cannot read any text because you have only image set on your ImageView/ImageButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html
It describes what to do to make you arr better in terms of Accessibility.

The **Labeling User Interface Elements** section should be important to you:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html#label-ui

Here is an example how to label a `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id=”@+id/add_note_button”
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src=”@drawable/add_note”
    android:contentDescription=”@string/add_note”/>
```

More information about android:contentDescription: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:contentDescription
You can set there any string from your resources so the message can be localized the same way as any other text displayed on screen etc.
Please note that `android:contentDescription` works even on view that have text associated (then the `android:contentDescription` will be spoken instead)

Comment: "android:contentDescription" is the solution. Dzięki Maćku ;)